# Pushsharp push notification only works with Sandbox and not production

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning, pushsharp

Hi all I am new to iOS development, I have put in the deep end to get push notifications. I found pushsharp and was using this tutorial

[Tutorial I a using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luO3e.png)

I have used a windows application instead of web application and added the latest pushsharp.  The code build and runs and I can get the push notification but only on sandbox.

[image: My Code]

[image: Xamarin iOS App bundle signing]

[image: Apple protal provisioning profile (Dev)]

I build my iOS app
Open the ipa on my iPad in xcode to install
once installed open the app and select allow to allow remote notifications
Get the device token when the app is opened and stick it in my winforms app
send a push using push sharp and bada bing bada boom it works like a charm.

I want to be able to use my production certificate as well. So I created a provisioning profile for App store. Created a signing request, created a certificate and in my provisioning profile section on apple portal i can see my new provisioning profile

[image: New Distribution provisioning profile created and Installed]

[image: Xamarin iOS app bundle signing now looks like this]

I am able to build my iOS app successfully however when i try and install the ipa onto my ipad i get an error

**App installation failed** 
a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Is there a step which i have missed? Why do i get app installation error.

What will happen if I release a app which is using devcertificate to show push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `distribution provisioning profile` to run the app on your ipad directly.

The `iOS Distribution certificate` can only be used to build an app that will be installed via the **App Store**.

You need to use either a `development` profile, or an `enterprise` distribution profile to install on test devices.

If you want to test a beat version, you can test the app using `TestFlight`.

Here are some way to [test a beat version](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev2539d985f).

> What will happen if I release a app which is using devcertificate to
>   show push notifications?

You have to use a p`roduction push certificate` to push notification in release mode.